# Flutter/Dart - Transparent Background to CircularProgressIndicator on a Loading Future?

Tags: flutter, dart, spinner, future, opacity

At the moment I get a white background with a spinning `CircularProgressIndicator` when I swipe to a new route. The new route has a `Future` that fetches data from a `HTTP Post`. Instead I'd like the background of the original page to remain behind the spinner until the future completes and the transition happens. So how do I make the spinners' background transparent instead of white? Here's the code to the future which I assume is where the spinner gets triggered;

```
FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>> replyStage({String replyid, String replytitle}) {
  return new FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>>(
    future: downloadReplyJSON(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<ReplyContent> replycrafts = snapshot.data;
        return StageBuilderVR(replycrafts, replytitle);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
}
```

And here's the code which swipes to the future;

```
onSwipeUp: () {
Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
}
```

And the code for the `PageRouteBuilder`:

```
Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => ReplyHome(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      var begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      var end = Offset.zero;
      var curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created a dummy Page that graphically mirrored the previous page with all the graphic elements of the previous page and none of the code.  I put that in place of the CircularProgressIndicator. I don't know if it's ideal, but it seems to work well.

```
FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>> replyStage({String replyid, String replytitle}) {
  return new FutureBuilder<List<ReplyContent>>(
    future: downloadReplyJSON(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<ReplyContent> replycrafts = snapshot.data;
        return StageBuilderVR(replycrafts, replytitle);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }
      return DummyPage();
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use showDialog to open a dialog which will open a transparent background with the AlertDialog, You can return your own stateful widget. Instead of streamBuilder just use future Builder.

try following code:

```
void uploadAndShowProgress() async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: uploadFile(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              StorageTaskEvent event = snapshot.data;
              final _snapshot = event.snapshot;
              _progress = _snapshot.bytesTransferred / _snapshot.totalByteCount;
            } else {
              //*  pop when there's no data or error...
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }

            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              SnackbarWidget.showSnackbar(
                  content: Text(snapshot.error.toString()), context: context);
            }

            return AlertDialogWidget(progress: _progress);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I got an underline red error on "context" in "context: context".

Comment: I've just re-edited the op with the code which calls the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Opacity(
          opacity: _isLoading ? 1.0 : 0, 
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: I wrapped the circularprogressindicator with the stack but Android Studio underlined "_isLoading" in red. How do I check if it's loading?

Comment: You write like to this;  return Opacity(
          opacity: 1.0, 
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),

Comment: Any chance you could edit your answer to show where I should write; return Opacity( opacity: 1.0, child: CircularProgressIndicator(), ), ?

Comment: That gave me a transparent CircularProgressIndicator(), instead of a transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

this function pushes route with transparent background

```
onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                        opaque: false,
                        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
                          return MyTransperentRoute();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
```

so in your CircularProgressIndicator page you can change background color of the root Widget like `color: Colors.transperent` or a plain `Container` without any color set will achieve the effect you need

```
class MyTrnsperentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

see the working code on dartpad [here](https://dartpad.dev/0186c14cfb181c6bdcbe48c89827d73d)

Comment: What should I put for "pageBuilder: (_, __, ___" ?

Comment: Use as is, they're parameters of the function, if you ctrl click on it you'll see what they are

Comment: Control click tells me "No usages found in all places".

Comment: Let's see how you're using it, you have to import

Comment: I tried adding your suggestion of  "PageRouteBuilder(
                        opaque: false," by using the example at Flutter.dev but the background remains a solid white during the transition. This is probably coming from the progress bars from within the future. Here's the code I used from the flutter.dev example; https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220533/discussion-between-yadu-and-meggy).